# Integral of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \, \cos^{2}(\theta) f_{\Theta}(\theta) \, d\theta$

Tags: integration, gaussian-integral, gaussian

What is the value of the integral

$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \, \cos^{2}(\theta) f_{\Theta}(\theta) \, d\theta$$

where $f_{\Theta}(\theta)$ is the gaussian pdf with mean $0$ and variance $1$

Comment: Use the double angle formula and properties of the Fourier transform and Gaussians.

Comment: could you show me a few steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By substituting $$\cos^2\theta=0.5+0.5\cos 2\theta=0.5+0.25(e^{2i\theta}+e^{-2i\theta})$$we have $$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \cos^{2}(\theta) f_{\Theta}(\theta)  d\theta=0.5+0.25\int_{-\infty}^\infty {1\over \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\theta^2\over 2}(e^{2i\theta}+e^{-2i\theta})d\theta$$From the other side
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\theta^2\over 2}e^{ki\theta}d\theta
{=
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\theta^2\over 2}e^{ki\theta}e^{-{(ki)^2\over 2}}e^{{(ki)^2\over 2}}d\theta
\\=
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(\theta-ki)^2\over 2}e^{-{k^2\over 2}}d\theta
\\=
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\theta^2\over 2}e^{-{k^2\over 2}}d\theta
\\=
\sqrt{2\pi}e^{-{k^2\over 2}}
}
$$hence 
$$
I=0.5+0.5e^{-2}
$$